# Tag synonym request: [http-referer], [referrer], [referer] -> [http-referer]

Tags: support, synonym-request

Three tags, referring to the same topic:

- [referrer](/questions/tagged/referrer) — eg JavaScript: `document.referrer`
- [referer](/questions/tagged/referer) and [http-referer](/questions/tagged/http-referer) — eg PHP: `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`

Each of these tags are just as frequently used as the other. I suggest to make `referrer` and `referer` a synonym of `http-referer`, because the latter contains the best description of the feature, and already contains a wiki excerpt.

Comment: +1 for the correct spelling of "referer". Everybody knows "referrer" was a fluke.

Comment: Ugh, that misspelling bothers me so.